# PHP cURL delay the execution for few seconds

Tags: php, curl, sleep, php-curl

I'm trying to get the Bing search count result using PHP cURL.

I tried cURL but the response is not returning any result. It is returning only the header and footer of the Bing search page.

**My code:**

```
$url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:mysite.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
sleep(10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Output HTML:**
[image]

Then I tried with Python with sleep.

```
url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:mysite.com";
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
print(browser.page_source)  # results
```

And this returned the HTML with Bing search result count.

```
    ......
    <span class="sb_count" data-bm="4">465 results</span>
    .....
```

Similar to Python how can I sleep PHP cURL execution in between for few seconds and get the search result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cURL is returned fastly before the cURLed url prepares the result`...this doesn't make any sense. cURL sends a HTTP request, and then it waits for the response. cURL won't return a response until the remote server sends back some data. That is a hard fact. So maybe explain to us what response you're seeing, and what response you expected? I'm going to hazard a guess that the remote site uses some JavaScript/AJAX to load extra content, and you've forgotten about the fact that cURL cannot execute Javascript. so all you get back is the HTML returned by the initial basic HTTP request.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the response. I have edited my question. Please see it.

Comment: I don't know python much, what is the `browser` variable? Does it represent a headless browser? If so it might have the capability to execute javascript, which may be the difference here. I don't know but I'd guess there is a headless browser library for php somewhere which you could try

Comment: It's a good point actually - I would echo the answer below: why aren't you using the API?

Comment: @ADyson We were using PHP cURL to get Bing search result count for last 2 years in our application. For last few months it seems to be not working. Definitely will try API. But initially I was just trying to make existing PHP cURL method working.

Comment: In which application? Python or php? But maybe Bing changed their UI and made it use more javascript than before, they don't have to warn you about it because it's not intended that you scrape results from it, it's meant for human users in a browser. The API is intended for other programs to consume the data and will be more stable, and warnings of breaking changes will be published ahead of time. That's why the API exists.

Comment: @ADyson We are using PHP only in our application.

Comment: OK well then if this was working before I'd expect the issue was that previously Bing was generating results without the use of JavaScript and maybe they changed that. As mentioned before, please start using the API, which will make parsing the results easier and also not leave you at the whim of unexpected changes by the UI designers.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a) not feasible and b) questionable.
There's a [Bing Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/), which appears more likely.